# Reading different kind of variables of unknown quantity from a .txt file line by line

Tags: c

I need to read an integer,a string and then integers of unknown quantity from the .txt file.And this should be done line by line.

An example .txt file:

```
541 Andy  76 55 84 80
841 Kevin 51 37 60 55 71 68
418 Erik 25 85 40
966 Martha  64 82 71 83 55
```

The output should be like:

```
ID:541 Name:Andy Values: [76, 55, 84, 80]
ID:841 Name:Kevin Values: [51, 37, 60, 55, 71, 68]
ID:418 Name:Erik Values: [25, 85, 40]
ID:966 Name:Martha Values: [64, 82, 71, 83, 55]
```

The problem is, I don't know how many values a person has.So my code should keep adding the new integers to an array until it sees the end of the line.I will have to pass these information to functions after this.So simply printing these to screen is not enough.I should be able to access and use them.And I can't scan all the .txt file (so can't use fscanf) because I need to pass them to functions person by person.

Comment: Allocate the array dynamically with `malloc()`. If there are more numbers on the line, increase its size with `realloc()`. Keep doing this in a loop.

Comment: [Reading words in line and putting them in array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19665229/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The answer there has a hard-coded limit on the number of words. Not a good design to mimic.

Comment: @Barmar you don't need to hardcode, just keep splitting the tokens until there's no token in the line

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc But he needs to put all the numbers into an array.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The answer in that question has `char words[6][20];` so it can only read 6 words from the line. How does that answer help him with this question about reading an arbitrary amount of numbers into an array?

Comment: @Barmar yes, split the token, convert to int then store in a dynamic array like you said. I just point to an example to use strtok

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I misunderstood, I thought you were pointing him to a solution to the array problem.

Comment: @barmar Disagree that a hard-coded limit on the number of words is [bad design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131223/reading-different-kind-of-variables-of-unknown-quantity-from-a-txt-file-line-by#comment73340724_43131223).  Certainly the limit should be very generous.  IMO, an high upper bound is prudent against hacker attacks.  Without a limit, a hacker can exploit and overwhelm resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with defining a `Person` structure

```
struct Person {
    int id;
    char *name;
    int *nums;
    size_t nums_size;
};
```

and an array of `Person`s.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 128
struct Person *persons;
int persons_index = 0;
size_t persons_size = BUFFER_SIZE;
persons = malloc(persons_size * sizeof(struct Person));
```

In a loop, read one character at a time using `fgetc` until you encounter a newline character normally `\n` on Unix-like systems. Note that you should always check for buffer overruns and extend the buffer as necessary.

```
char *buffer;
int buffer_index = 0;
size_t buffer_size = BUFFER_SIZE;
buffer = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char));
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if (buffer_index > buffer_size - 2) {
        buffer_size *= 2;
        buffer = realloc(buffer, buffer_size);
    }

    if (c == '\n') {
        /* Tokenize here */
    } else {
        /* Store the character and null terminate the buffer */
    }
}
```

Given a whole line is in the buffer, tokenize the line using `strtok`. Convert each string integer using `atoi`. Converting the values followed by persons names is basically the same as above.

```
int nums_index = 0;
size_t nums_size = BUFFER_SIZE;
persons[persons_index].nums = malloc(nums_size * sizeof(int));
/* Assuming strtok has been called before for person's id and name */
while ((token = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
    if (nums_index > nums_size - 1) {
        nums_size *= 2;
        persons[persons_index].nums = realloc(
            persons[persons_index].nums, nums_size);
    }
    persons[persons_index].nums[nums_index] = atoi(token);
    nums_index++;
}
persons[persons_index].nums_size = nums_index;
```

Don't forget to `free` the buffer and the persons array with your done with them and please note that I left lots of details and error checkings out.